# Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::to(), 0 passed error laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I Want to send a email confirmation from laravel but I've the next error
error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::to(), 0 passed in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/medicalconnect3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailManager.php on line 484 and exactly 1 expected

**This is MailManager.php in line 484**

```
 @param  string  $method
         * @param  array  $parameters
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function __call($method, $parameters)
        {
            return $this->mailer()->$method(...$parameters);
    }
```

**This is my function verifyUser**

```
public function verifyUser(Request $request)
    {

        $verification_code = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::get('code');

        //first o get
        $user = User::where(['verification_code' => $verification_code])->first();

        if ($user != null) {
            $user->is_verified = 1;

            $user->save();
            return redirect()->route('login')->with(session()->flash('alert-success', 'Tu cuenta ha sido verificada exitosamente, por favor ingresa'));
        }

        return redirect()->route('login')->with(session()->flash('alert-danger', 'Upps código de verificación invalido '));
    }
```

**This is my register function**

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {

        $user = new User();
        $user->prefijo = $request->prefijo;
        $user->cedula = $request->cedula;
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->paterno = $request->paterno;
        $user->materno = $request->materno;
        $user->titulo = $request->titulo;
        $user->entidad = $request->entidad;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->telefono = $request->telefono;
        $user->ciudad = $request->ciudad;
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
        $user->verification_code = sha1(time());
        $user->save();

        if ($user != null) {

            //send email with verification link
            MailController::sendSignupEmail($user->name, $user->email, $user->verification_code);

            //show a message
            return redirect()->back()->with(session()->flash('alert-success', 'Tu cuenta ha sido creada. Por favor revisa tu email para realizar la verificación de la cuenta'));
        }

        //show error message
        return redirect()->back()->with(session()->flash('alert-danger', 'Upps algo salio mal, por favor vuelve a intentarlo '));
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Would you mind sharing the code from `MailController::sendSignupEmail`?

Comment: public static function sendSignupEmail($name, $email, $verification_code){

        $data = [

         'name' => $name,
         'verification_code' => $verification_code,

        ];

        Mail::to()->send(new SignupEmail($data));
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are forgetting to pass `$email` as the first parameter of `Mail::to()->` should be `Mail::to((new User(['email' => $email])))->`.

The first parameter is expecting a `\Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable` (https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Notifications/Notifiable.html)

Please take a look at https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Mail.html

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

Remove this from your mail.php config file

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
```

and replace it with

```
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),
```